# jQuery upgrade - jquery.mobile adding classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

We are currently upgrading our jQuery version from 1.10 to 3.3.1

As a result, we have also had to install jquery.mobile v1.5.0 (as this is the only one compatible with v3)

jquery.mobile is adding classes to my page and also additional div elements (`data-role="page"` for example)

is there a way to stop jquery.mobile doing this/disabling it. The layout of my page is being compromised with these new classes

Comment: I've not used that version of jQuery mobile, but it's unlikely you can amend this behaviour. jQm will rely on those additional classes and attributes for its operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable jQM's `$.mobile.autoInitializePage` on `mobileinit`.

```
<head>
  <!-- jQuery.js here -->
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
  </script>
  <!-- jQuery Mobile.js here -->
</head>
```

To initialize framework manually, use `$.mobile.initializePage();`.

Comment: You are alive :-)

Comment: @Gajotres I couldn't duplicate-answer close it, so I had to add one ;)